# Unison and `prop` files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, synchronization, unison

Sometimes, when one syncs between two machines in unison there are `prop` files appearing all over the place. This happens because the timestamps of the to-be-synched files, obviously don't match. A solution would be to set `times = True` and then I am copying not only the contents but the modification times as well. My question is, is there any drawback, caveat, trap in doing so? Can I "shoot my self in the leg" somehow?

Comment: I can't think of anything, and looking in the [Unison manual](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) I didn't see any such considerations pointed out about using the `time` option, so I think you're good. :)